# Weibull Survival Model in R

Tags: r, survival

If I run a Weibull survival model in R with the code

```
survreg(Surv(t,delta)~expalatory variables, dist="w")
```

how do I interpret the output of the model? That is, is the form of the model just $1-\exp(e/\lambda)^k)$ with $\lambda$ the scale and $k$ the shape or does it take a different form?

I have found something which says that the output is of the form $$\exp(-\exp(-\alpha_0-\alpha_1-\ldots)^kx^k),$$ where the $\alpha_i$ are the coefficients of the covariates. If so, the output would give me the following parameters:

$$k=k \quad \mbox{and} \quad \lambda=\frac{1}{\exp(-\alpha_0-\alpha_1\ldots)}.$$

Comment: Slight algebra turns you "output of the form..." to a*exp(-x^k).  I don't think that is correct.  That looks like a cousin of the Arrhenius equation.

Comment: @EngrStudent Sorry i don't understand what you are saying here?

Comment: Here is the general form of Weibull.  
http://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda3668.htm

Comment: @EngrStudent Thanks, I am aware of the form of the Weibull Distribution. The problem I have is that if I run survreg with the Weibull distribution in R then it gives the shape and scale parameter, however I these have been transformed in some way (to make it fit in more  general distribution family) and I need to know what the transformation is so that I can get the actual shape and scale parameters.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ok so I'm just going to post an answer here using the R help that DWin described. Using the function `rweibull` in R gives the usual form of the Weibull distribution, with its cumulative function being:

$$F(x)=1-\exp(-\left ( \frac{x}{b}\right )^a)$$

So we will denote the shape parameter of `rweibull` by $a$ and the scale parameter of `rweibull` by $b$.

Now the problem is that the output of `survreg` gives both shape and scale parameters which are not the same as the shape and scale parameters from `rweibull`. Let us denote the shape parameter from `survreg` as $a_s$ and the scale parameter of `survreg` by $b_s$.

Then, from `?survreg` we have that:

> survreg's scale  =    1/(rweibull shape)
>
> survreg's intercept = log(rweibull scale)

So this gives us that:

$$a=\frac{1}{b_s}\quad \mbox{and} \quad b=\exp(a_s)$$

So if we suppose that we run the function `survreg` with $n$ covariates, then the output will be:

$\alpha_0,\ldots, \alpha_{n-1}$, the coefficents of the covariates and some scale parameter $k$. The Weibull model given in standard form is then given by:

$$F(x)=1-\exp\left (- \left (\frac{x}{\exp(\alpha_0+\alpha_1+\ldots +\alpha_{n-1})} \right ) ^{\frac{1}{k}}\right )$$

Answer (score 6):

I'd like to add an answer with a code example for further clarity.

What we're essentially after is taking the `survreg` output model and derive from it the survival function. To avoid the common notation confusion I'll actually go ahead and show the code that does that:

```
fit <- survreg(Surv(time,status) ~ age, data=stanford2) # this is the survreg output model
survreg.lp <- predict(fit, type = "lp")
survreg.scale <- fit$scale

# this is the survival function!
S_t <- function(t, survreg.scale, survreg.lp){
  shape <- 1/survreg.scale 
  scale <- exp(survreg.lp)
  ans <- 1 - pweibull(t, shape = shape, scale = scale)
}
```

As mentioned by [vkehayas](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/97671/vkehayas) R's `pweibull` parameterisation is:

$$F(x) = 1-exp(-\left(\frac{x}{b}\right)^a$$

where `a` is the weibull distribution shape and `b` is the scale.

We then get that `a = 1/fit$scale` and `b = exp(predict(fit, type = "lp"))`

We can verify below that the derived survival function

```
# next let's verify it's correct:
fit <- survreg(Surv(time,status) ~ age, data=stanford2) # this is the survreg output model

# this is the survival function!
S_t <- function(t, survreg.scale, survreg.lp){
  shape <- 1/survreg.scale 
  scale <- exp(survreg.lp)
  ans <- 1 - pweibull(t, shape = shape, scale = scale)
}

new_dat <- data.frame(age = c(0, seq(min(stanford2$age), max(stanford2$age), length.out = 10)))

pct <- seq(0.01, 0.99, 0.01)

surv_curves <- sapply(pct,
                      function(x) predict(fit, type = "quantile", p = 1 - x,
                                          newdata = new_dat))

matplot(y = pct, t(surv_curves), type = "l")

# you can vary the below subject_i variable to see it works for all of them
subject_i <- 1
single_curve <- surv_curves[subject_i, ]
plot(single_curve, pct, type = "l") # this is we know to be true
  
times <- round(seq(1, max(single_curve), length.out = 100))
lp <- predict(fit, newdata = new_dat, type = "lp")[subject_i]
surv <- sapply(times, function(t) S_t(t, survreg.scale = fit$scale, survreg.lp = lp))
lines(times, surv, col = "red", lty = 2) # this is the new S_t function
# They match!
```

So, to summarize:

`a = 1/fit$scale` and `b = exp(predict(fit, type = "lp"))`

Hope this helps. I know I pulled a few hairs before figuring this out.

Comment: In your answer you're not using your derived function though, and you're plotting the results of predict(type = quantile)... I tried to plot the S_t over time and the results make no sense... could you update your answer to use S_t?

Comment: The 3rd line from the bottom uses the survival function I defined above. Maybe if you share what you tried I could try to help.

Answer (score 2):

The help page for `?Weibull` says:

> The Weibull distribution with shape parameter a and scale parameter b has density given by
>
> f(x) = (a/b) (x/b)^(a-1) exp(- (x/b)^a)

And then the help page for `?survreg` says:

```
# There are multiple ways to parameterize a Weibull distribution. The survreg 
# function embeds it in a general location-scale family, which is a 
# different parameterization than the rweibull function, and often leads
# to confusion.
#   survreg's scale  =    1/(rweibull shape)
#   survreg's intercept = log(rweibull scale)
```

And there is an elaboration of how this is handled in the Examples section of  `?survreg.distributions`

Comment: How would you incorporate exploratory variables in the the weibull function?

Comment: That's much too vague in it's current form. Why not post a question with description of a data layout?

Comment: I was trying to point out that your answer is not helpful in addressing OP question, just providing r help pages is not helpful.

Comment: Why is adding covariates helpful here?

Comment: The point that I thought was helpful is that the Weibull distribution implementation used in the R survival package is different than what is used in many textbooks (and in R's own rweibull.)